# export a file from a different git branch

Tags: git

Is there a simple way to export a single file from different git branch (local or remote) without checking out that branch?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
 git show experiment:docs/README.txt > /tmp/exported-README.txt
```

... for a local branch `experiment`.  For a branch that's in the repository you're referring to with the remote `origin`, you can do the following, similarly:

```
 git fetch origin
 git show origin/other-experiment:docs/README.txt > /tmp/exported-README-remote.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Yup

```
git show remote/branchname:path/to/file
```

If you want to save it directly, this might come in handy:

```
git_showfile () 
{ 
    if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
        return 255;
    fi;
    local fspec="$1";
    shift;
    local fname="$(basename "$fspec")";
    local fpath="$(dirname "$fspec")";
    local revision=HEAD;
    if [ $# -ge 1 ]; then
        revision="$1";
    fi;
    if [ -e "$fspec" ]; then
        echo not overwriting existing file;
    else
        mkdir -pv "$fpath" && git show "$revision:$fspec" > "$fspec";
    fi
}
```

**Edit:** ... which you would use as follows

```
git_showfile path/to/file
```

or

```
git_showfile path/to/file 237f723edcb89
```

etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can choose to check out a specific file from a reference:

`git checkout branch_or_hash path/to/file`

The current branch will stay the same, but the other file will also be present. It will also be added to the index.

Comment: I assumed that by "export", the OP meant putting a copy elsewhere and leaving the repository's working copy and index as they were before.  We'll see, I guess :)

Comment: Ah, I think your interpretation makes more sense indeed.